# Noob trying to combine while and if statements

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to learn C# and wanted to try making a simple program from scratch that asks the user to enter a number between 1-3, every number yields a lottery win and writing "exit" is supposed to exit the program. When one number is answered the user is supposed to be prompted to answer again until choosing to exit. No matter what I do when trying to combine a while loop and if statements I get errors or just infinite loops that won't stop. Probably some simple syntax misunderstanding.. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my code so far:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string userInput = "";
        Console.Write("Pick a number between 1-3, type 'exit' to stop the program: ");
        userInput = Console.ReadLine();


        while (userInput != "exit")

            if (userInput == "1")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You won a car");
            }
            else if (userInput == "2")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You won a boat");
            }
            else if (userInput == "3")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry, no luck this time. Try again");
            }
            else if (userInput == "exit")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exiting...");
                break
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The number has to be between 1-3, try again.");
            }
            Console.ReadLine()
            }


    }

}
```

}

Comment: your `userInput.ReadLine()` should be the first statement in the while loop...

Comment: You're a bit light on semicolons and open curly brackets; post syntax error free code please - this is not a compilable fragment, so it cannot be what youre using to hit your problem

Comment: Typically I would just fix a question poster's format, but since your code format issue may actually be a big part of the problem, I can't. You should though. Maybe put it in code fences. [Here is a formatted version](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KTiPef) complete with a few more braces and semicolons.

Comment: Big thanks for the input. Wrapping my head around the syntax/braces/semicolons is something I'm working on. Getting there, hopefully!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string userInput = "";
        Console.Write("Pick a number between 1-3, type 'exit' to stop the program: ");
        userInput = Console.ReadLine();


        while (userInput != "exit")
        {

            if (userInput == "1")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You won a car");
            }
            else if (userInput == "2")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You won a boat");
            }
            else if (userInput == "3")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry, no luck this time. Try again");
            }
            else if (userInput == "exit")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exiting...");
                break
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The number has to be between 1-3, try again.");
            }
            userInput = Console.ReadLine()
            }


    }

}
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The value of `userInput` is never updated in the loop, which means that each time the loop runs, the value stays the same.

A solution is to move the prompt and the reading into the start of the loop.

Comment: and remove the extra `Console.ReadLine()` at the end of the loop

Comment: Thanks a lot! Starting to grasp this now.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Zayenz's answer, this is the key to all infinite loops; the circumstance evaluated that decides whether or not to begin the loop is always true. If you ever have this problem again, you just need to look at the code to make sure that whatever should break you out of the loop actually changes whatever criteria it needs to in order to make the condition false;

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification! Much appreciated, now I get it!